# How can I mark a Work Item as favorite in Visual studio (2015)?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I know I can add queries to favorites and see team favorite queries, but I see no option to add a work item handle (id) to a favorite list of my own, so that I can reach them with a single click.

This gets handy when I am tracking the integration progress of a certion change request (and by extension, its child tasks) or just want to have a feature handy when I want to create from it a new linked task.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such kind of feature in VS2015. You could only drag queries to **My Faviorites** list.

As a workaround, you could now [follow (or watch) a work item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/follow-work-items) in web portal.

- To setup an alert for tracking changes to a single work item, just
  click on the new “**Follow**” button in the form.
- When you follow a work item, you’ll be notified of subsequent
  comments, field, links, and attachment changes by other members of
  your account.

[image]

*Note: The Follow a work item feature is available from  TFS 2017. Besides,  you [must configure an SMTP sever](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/setup-customize-alerts) for the follow features to work.*

Actually, it's more easy to track work items from web portal instead of Visual Studio.

[image]